# Usability Test Facilitating and Synthesis - how long does it take you to do?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, usability-study

We completed 6 usability tests last week. The last test was completed at the end of day on Thursday and the meeting to present findings was scheduled for noon on Monday. I felt like this wasn't enough time to synthesize everything and have it ready to report the observations and recommendations so I've been given to the end of this week to finish it.

**How long does it take you to synthesize usability test results?**

Just trying to get an idea to gauge my own performance.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it depends how complex the thing you are testing is.

You'll get better results if you have time to think about it:  not time in front of a screen but time driving around / lying in the bath /cooking meals.

What you want is your subconscious mind to be mulling it over and coming up with theories as to why person X did action Y.

This mulling it over process is how various scientific theories came about.

Here's a couple of examples which may - or may not - be true:

https://www.beliefnet.com/columnists/dreamgates/2012/01/daydreams-of-science-the-benzene-ouroboros-and-the-clapham-omnibus.html

The psychological process is that by not thinking directly about the problem bits of one's subconscious mind grind away as a kind of 'background task'.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty tight timeline IMO. It really does depend on what your organization is like. Taking a look at different UX Maturity models could help you understand why you're only be given a little time for analysis and how you might want to look at growing in the future, or make some goals for your area.
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-stages-1-4/

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-maturity-stages-5-8/

https://www.testingtime.com/en/blog/6-degrees-ux-maturity-scale/

I've worked at an Ad Agency where I build up UX from level 1-3 and it was honestly a battle to get to do any testing, let alone analysis sometimes. Where I'm at now we have 2 week sprints and I'll get a sprint or two for analysis alone.